# What do you call the act of searching for something by walking?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The police and dog spent the whole night [...] the area.

Is *searching* the only word? Or there are other ones?

Comment: Mplungjan's "Combing" is an excellent answer and I've upvoted it but I'm wondering what your search for "searching" synonyms produced?  Which synonyms did you find and why did you reject them?

Comment: The title and example lead me to believe you were on a quest for *grid search*, not a synonym.

Comment: Funnily enough _policing_ in the US military means to walk the area searching for trash etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Combing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/comb) (as a synonym for searching, not adjusting your hair with a utensil)

**The police and dog spent the whole night combing the area**

> comb verb [T] (SEARCH)
>
> › to search a place or an area very carefully in order to find something:
> The police **combed** the whole area for evidence.
> <sub>Cambridge</sub>

Weird coincidence:

> - Charlie Hebdo attack: Hundreds of elite armed police ***comb*** woodland ... *Independent*
> - Armed police ***scour*** forest as Charlie Hebdo shooting... *Telegraph*

---

Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtkK3eijBso

> COMB THE DESERT!

[image]

Comment: that's the closest! +1

Comment: "combing" also fits but I feel it's a figure of speech.  I just can't remember which.

Comment: See my update for examples from real life. From Spaceballs: "COMB THE DESERT"

Comment: I like "searching" best, since the thought of dogs "combing" is a little jarring. Maybe "police *with* their dogs" would be enough to soften that.

Comment: "Search dogs, police officers to comb Burrell High School"

Comment: @mplungjan:  What does a mere citation mean? One can find on the internet people using language precisely as well as sloppily.

Comment: Yes, and as many people reading them as jarring. I just wanted to add one with police and dogs

Comment: And we are now where? ;)

Comment: Does "combing" have to be done on foot necessarily?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: What does combing have to do with walking?  Don't understand how this is an accepted answer.

Comment: @dennisdeems What is confusing you? Combing is **searching** thoroughly - likely on foot especially if you have dogs. But I could imagine someone combing an area in a helicopter or combing a high resolution image with a magnifying glass. The question is about searching more than walking since we are talking about police with dogs.

Comment: @mplungjan nothing is confusing me.  Combing is a metaphor for exhaustive searching.  It has nothing to do with being on foot.  The phrase "combing the archives" is often encountered in academic circles.  Do you imagine scholars tromping over books with dogs in tow?  The question is explicitly about "searching by walking".

Comment: Perhaps the emphasis on "walking" is a red herring which the querent doesn't actually care about.

Comment: I guess the dogs are not flying dogs ;)

Comment: Excellent Star Wars reference!

Comment: Space Balls :) .

Answer (score 18):

Nothing wrong with **"searching"** but if you want another word, I suggest **"scouring"**.

- **"The police and dogs spent the whole night scouring the area"** sounds perfect.

> scour (verb) "to look through (as a place) carefully or thoroughly in an effort to find or discover something."
>
> - "The police **scoured the city** for the Typhoid Mary of this latest epidemic." [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/scour)
> - " The detective **scoured the scene of the crime** for clues."

[image: police scour bushland for body after tip-off on missing boy]

Police scour bushland for body after tip-off on missing boy.  From [ABC NEWS](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-03-02/police-search-bushland-missing-boy-william-tyrell/6272660)

Comment: I'm not sure that I would use "scour" to describe what search parties accompanied by dogs are doing. Dogs follow a scent trail, whereas "scouring" is an action performed by the eyes.

Comment: See my comment at mplungjan

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're looking for, "canvass" could also work: the police canvassed the area.  This specifically implies talking to people, however, in order to get feedback - so it doesn't work in a wilderness setting.

Comment: +1, I was also thinking canvassing. It typically implies inquiry in modern usage, but according to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/canvass it can also just refer to "Close inspection; scrutiny" or "to examine carefully".

Answer (score 3):

For walking, "patrolling" works best.

[Patrol](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patrol): the act of walking or going around or through an area, building, etc., in order to make sure that it is safe.

Comment: Patrolling is not searching.

Comment: Combing is not walking.

Comment: @dennisdeems, combing can be walking in the context of searching for something.  You can comb a neighborhood which can be done while walking, or you can comb a building - also done by walking.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez Of course it can.  It can be done while walking, while standing, while sitting,  while lounging, while bathing.

Comment: @dennisdeems, so then why did you say in your comment, "Combing is not walking"?

Comment: @dennisdeems You would likely not "comb" (as a synonym for searching)  an area while standing still - (perhaps one might envision someone using binoculars) but combing an area to my mind means moving around. You can comb the files in a file cabinet while sitting or standing still, but then you would not use dogs. Please note that the verb COMB is not adjusting your hair with a utensil in this discussion

Comment: @mplungjan as made delightfully explicit by the fun image you posted, it is the nature of that utensil which allows us to use the verb in this sense in the first place. ;)

Comment: I disagree with claim that patrolling is not searching. If you are not keeping your eyes wide open for anything out of the ordinary, you're not patrolling. You're therefore, by definition, searching.

Comment: Patrolling generally suggests something defensive, looking out for all threats, and, in most cases, you are watching out for mobile, incoming entities.  You are watching for any item in a category of things that might be there or might be coming in.  This is distinct enough from a *search* that is looking for a specific item that "patrol" would not really work for what the asker wants.

Answer (score 3):

[Hunt high and low](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hunt+high+and+low) (for someone or something) and *look high and low* (for someone or something);

> - Fig. to look carefully in every possible place for someone or something. We looked high and low for the right teacher. The Smiths are searching high and low for the home of their dreams. (AHD)

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

A quick [search onMerriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/search) and [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/searching) suggests that there is no single word meaning *to search for something by walking* in the English language.

If *by walking* constitutes an important piece of information, I suggest you make it explicit by using e.g.:

> He searched the woods *on foot.*

As for synonyms for *searching* I've got nothing to add to the previous answers.

Comment: @choster Thank you for the edits. Seems like I need to exercise my writing skills more. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a systematic search, quartering (see meaning 7 [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quartering)) might work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply ***walking***.

> to follow on foot for the purpose of measuring, surveying, or inspecting
>
> *walk a boundary*  [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walk)

Example:

> An officer soon spotted Long running on the railroad tracks behind the
>   bank, and **police brought in a police dog and walked the area** around the bank to track him.
>
> [liveleak.com](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=d38_1346884531&comments=1&selected_view_mode=desktop#GHWVGj7mTDH73ywa.99)

Comment: I see the example. I have never seen it used in that sense

Comment: The context should indicate that it is about searching because "walk" might mean patrolling also in a similar sense. There are a lot of senses of "walk" but this sense is exactly "searching/inspecting on foot" and not by other means.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the word *scout.*

[Merriam-Websiter defines it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scout) as "to explore an area to obtain information (as about an enemy)" or "to make a search."

Here's an example of its usage in a context similar to your question:

> Police scouted the area for someone matching the description but turned up nobody, the report states.

[Source](http://www.arkansasonline.com/news/2013/sep/24/purse-snatched-outside-little-rock-library/)

Comment: Does that suggest "on foot?"

Answer (score 1):

''Traversing'' would be the mathematical or computer science term.

> The program traversed the entire filesystem checking for any remaining viruses.

Comment: "Scanning" would be even more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a Boy Scout the leaders taught us to "police the area" of a campsite when breaking it (shutting it down) before leaving: systematically searching on foot for any trash, gear or other conditions to address. The term is still [used officially](http://www.scouting.org/Philmont/Camping/Hikers/Shakedown/BreakingUpCamp.aspx):

> Form a line with your crew to police the area, picking up all trash
>   and making sure no gear is left behind.

So while the term is used consistently with the [Merriam-Webster primary definition of the verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/police):

> to control and keep order in (an area) by the use of police or
>   military forces

it does mean specifically the act of searching for something by walking. Which, since police officers do so as a matter of course, and are the main people in society who do so, the word "police" appears in most of this page's responses to this question. I think it's the most apropos term.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider *pounding*, as it is closely related by idiom.

> pound the pavement
>
> Walk the streets, especially in search of employment.
>
> A similar usage is *pound a beat*, meaning "to walk a particular route over and over"; it is nearly always applied to a police officer. [Early 1900s]
>
> See also: pavement, pound

<sup><sub>[The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pound+the+pavement) by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

This is more in the vein of the *patrolling* and *canvassing* answers, but it is an excellent stand-in when an investigation loses a sense of immediacy and starts to stretch over days. If the search through the night is fruitless, then police would fall back to pounding the pavement to gather evidence and witness statements.

Comment: There seems to be no hint of searching.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard Peruse used to describe someone looking at items in a store before, which makes me think it could be used in this instance as well, although, it might sound a tad less aggressive than how you might want to use it.

from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse:

> pe·ruse
>
> transitive verb
> 1 a :  to examine or consider with attention and in detail :  study
> b :  to look over or through in a casual or cursory manner

Comment: You can only peruse in the mind.

Answer (score -1):

(Collecting)

Police don't use a dog unless they're looking for something to obtain for criminal activity.
So technically they would be collecting evidence, otherwise why would it specify police and a dog.

This is the only answer that is acceptable if you put the common sense Factor into play for this scenario or question, again the question specifies a police officer and a dog in the same situation about to obtain something therefore an action which is a verb; the only answer can be listed at the top of this paragraph.

Comment: Collecting by itself doesn't fit the sample sentence in the question.